# Good tutorial to create Win32 toolbar?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I want to add a toolbar and know which tool was clicked. I'd also like to be able to change the toolbar's buttons' bitmap after theyve been created MSDN is fairly breif on all of this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out these [tutorials](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/toolbar/).

Grz, Kris.

Answer (score 2):

If you like to learn by example then you may find this code useful. It's a Windows toolbar wrapper class I created some time ago. It's somewhat advanced though because it uses Custom Draw.

[WindowsToolbar.h](http://code.google.com/p/xulwin/source/browse/trunk/XULWin/include/XULWin/WindowsToolbar.h)
[WindowsToolbar.cpp](http://code.google.com/p/xulwin/source/browse/trunk/XULWin/src/WindowsToolbar.cpp)
[WindowsToolbarItem.h](http://code.google.com/p/xulwin/source/browse/trunk/XULWin/include/XULWin/WindowsToolbarItem.h)
[WindowsToolbarItem.cpp](http://code.google.com/p/xulwin/source/browse/trunk/XULWin/src/WindowsToolbarItem.cpp)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.functionx.com/win32/